# phpbb and filesystem storage

Tags: phpbb

Can I save the images file on filesystem (no db) in phpbb?

Comment: I have been teeming over Google all day, and I haven't found anything on the subject. What 'images file' are you speaking of? The uploaded avatars?

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box this is not possible, nor can I find any plugins that would give you this functionality.

The files do get saved on the filesystem sort of - if you view the files in /files these are the files attached to posts but without any meta data (this is what the database supplies) the link is the physical_filename column in the _attachments table.

Comment: What sort of meta data is saved in the DB? If the files are valid JPEG/PNG/GIF files, then they should already contain the image meta data in the header sections of each respective file format (especially the meta data that is required for rendering the image, e.g. image dimensions, palette info, format, etc.).

Comment: The files saved are not valid files, it is almost like they are a hash of information.  It may be possible to create the file again just using the stored information on the file system but I doubt it since you would have nothing to go on (if you should try and create a png, or gif, or whatever)

Comment: That's really odd. I mean, it's best to store binary file data off database and simply reference them by filename, so at least there's that. But I see no advantage to storing invalid/partial image files directly on the file system and then having to re-constitute them using data from the database (and do this for every request?).

Comment: I don't agree with it either, but it seems to be the way of it for phpBB - perhaps a misguided security attempt?